# how to delete 2 rows with one query with mysql

Tags: mysql

Hi guys how i can delete 2 rows in one query from one table. my code is:

```
DELETE FROM panel_friends
                WHERE friends_friend_id = ' . $k . ' AND friends_member_id = ' . $key2
AND
                WHERE friends_friend_id = ' . $k2 . ' AND friends_member_id = ' . $key
```

Comment: Clearly you haven't read the documentation on [`DELETE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html) or you'd know that wasn't valid SQL. Please, check there first. There's a very thorough explanation as to what's allowed and what's not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DELETE
FROM    panel_friends
WHERE   (friends_friend_id = :k1 AND friends_member_id = :k2)
        OR
        (friends_friend_id = :k2 AND friends_member_id = :k1)
```